# Removing Danish Oil spills

Tags: kitchens

We recently recoated our worktop with Danish Oil and noticed later that some oil had dripped down our silver effect washing machine. We have tried soapy water and white spirit but can't remove the stains. Does anyone have any suggestionsfor what we could use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to woodworking discussions, it looks like any of the "usual suspect" organic solvents should be able to cut this polymerizing oil finish -- turpentine, mineral spirits, paint thinner, naptha.

Comment: My own tests (self answer to the question I've flagged as duplicate) indicate that once cured naphtha and mineral (white) spirit do little to nothing, but cellulose thinners and acetone are worth a try. In this case you'd need to check they don't affect the finish underneath.